# How prove this $\dfrac{x^y}{y^x}\ge (1+\ln{3})x-(1+\ln{3})y+1$?

Tags: inequality

let $x>0,y>0,z>0$, and $x+y+z=1$,prove that

$$\dfrac{x^y}{y^x}+\dfrac{y^z}{z^y}+\dfrac{z^x}{x^z}\ge 3$$

my idea: let $f(x,y)=\dfrac{x^y}{y^x}$

then we consider
$$f(x,y)\ge g(x,y)=px+qy+r$$

so $$p=\dfrac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}|_{(x,y)=(1/3,1/3)}=1+\ln{3}$$
 $$q=\dfrac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}|_{(x,y)=(1/3,1/3)}=-(1+\ln{3})$$
$$f(1/3,1/3)=g(1/3,1/3)$$ then we have $r=1$

so  we have

$$\dfrac{x^y}{y^x}\ge (1+\ln{3})x-(1+\ln{3})y+1$$

my question:
How prove that:$$\dfrac{x^y}{y^x}\ge (1+\ln{3})x-(1+\ln{3})y+1$$? a true or flase?

Now we have find this flase. so we can consider other methods. Thank you everyone.

oh,I have consider this methods.

let $$a=\dfrac{x^y}{y^x},b=\dfrac{y^z}{z^y},c=\dfrac{z^x}{x^z}$$

then $$a=y\ln{x}-x\ln{y},b=z\ln{y}-y\ln{z},c=x\ln{z}-z\ln{x}$$
and we have
$$az+bx+yc=0$$

so we use this Jensen

$$e^a+e^b+e^c\ge 3e^{\frac{za+xb+yc}{x+y+z}}=3$$

so
$$\dfrac{x^y}{y^x}+\dfrac{y^z}{z^y}+\dfrac{z^x}{x^z}\ge 3$$

I belived have other nice methods. Thank you

Comment: $x=2$ and $y=1$ is a counterexample.

Comment: False, consider $x=y+\delta$, then for the left side, it should be around $1+(1-\log y)\delta$

Comment: But $(1+\ln{3})x-(1+\ln{3})y+1=1+(1+\ln{3})\delta$,  you let $y=\dfrac{1}{3}$, then $1+(1-\log{y})\delta=1+(1+\ln{3})\delta$

Comment: It fails for $x=0.45$ and $y=0.4$.

Comment: Oh,Yeah, Thank you.http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%280.45%29%5E%280.4%29%29%2F%28%280.4%29%5E%280.45%29%29-%281%2Bln3%29*%280.05%29-1

Comment: Btw, the way I found it was by randomizing values of $x$ and $y$ with $x+y<1$ until an example occurred. I don't have an idea about your original problem, sorry.