# How to prove this inequality $\frac{x^y}{y^x}+\frac{y^z}{z^y}+\frac{z^x}{x^z}\ge 3$

Tags: inequality

> let $x,y,z$ be positive numbers, and such $x+y+z=1$

show that
$$\dfrac{x^y}{y^x}+\dfrac{y^z}{z^y}+\dfrac{z^x}{x^z}\ge 3$$

My try:

> let
>   $$a=\ln{\dfrac{x^y}{y^x}},b=\ln{\dfrac{y^z}{z^y}},c=\ln{\dfrac{z^x}{x^z}}$$
>   so
>   $$a=y\ln{x}-x\ln{y},b=z\ln{y}-y\ln{z},c=x\ln{z}-z\ln{x}$$
>   and we note 
>   $$az+bx+yc=(y\ln{x}-x\ln{y})z+(z\ln{y}-y\ln{z})x+(x\ln{z}-z\ln{x})y=0$$
>   so
>   $$\dfrac{x^y}{y^x}+\dfrac{y^z}{z^y}+\dfrac{z^x}{x^z}=e^a+e^b+e^c$$
>   so
>   $$\Longleftrightarrow e^a+e^b+e^c\ge 3$$
>   But then I can't prove it.

If this problem is to prove
$$ze^a+xe^b+ye^c\ge 3,$$
I can prove it,because 
$$ze^a+xe^b+ye^c\ge=\dfrac{z}{x+y+z}e^a+\dfrac{x}{x+y+z}e^b+\dfrac{y}{x+y+z}e^c$$
so
use Jensen's inequality,we have
$$ze^a+xe^b+ye^c\ge e^{\dfrac{az+bx+yc}{x+y+z}}=3$$

This problem comes from [How prove this $\dfrac{x^y}{y^x}\ge (1+\ln{3})x-(1+\ln{3})y+1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346974/how-prove-this-dfracxyyx-ge-1-ln3x-1-ln3y1?rq=1)

Thank you very much!

Comment: without $x+y+z=1$, the equality is OK also.

Comment: $ze^a+xe^b+ye^c\ge e^{\frac{az+bx+yc}{x+y+z}}=1$

Comment: why without this problem is also?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another solution.
Without loss of generality, we can assume that $0<x\le y\le z$ and so $x=az$, $y=bz$, $0<a\le b\le1$. By the AM-GM inequality, we find that
\begin{align}
\frac{x^y}{y^x}+\frac{y^z}{z^y}+\frac{z^x}{x^z}&\ge 3\sqrt[3]{x^{y-z}y^{z-x}z^{x-y}}=3\sqrt[3]{(az)^{(b-1)z}(bz)^{(1-a)z}z^{(a-b)z}}=3\sqrt[3]{a^{(b-1)z}b^{(1-a)z}}=\\
&=3(a^{b-1}b^{1-a})^{z/3}
\end{align}
so we only need to prove that $a^{b-1}b^{1-a}\ge1$, which Hansen did in the answer below. We also see that the condition $x+y+z=1$ is not needed.

Comment: this is the right answer.+1

Comment: Great answer, Walt! Do you have a bitcoin wallet?

Comment: @Anonomous No, but I have a reputation wallet!

Comment: The second solution is wrong. $b\log(a)<a\log(a)$ because $\log(a)<0$.

Comment: However, the solution can be salvaged by looking at $g(x) = -(1-x)\log(a)+(1-a)\log(x)$. It is easy to see $g$ is a concave function with $g(a)=g(1)=0$. So, $g(b)>0,\,\forall a<b<1$.

Comment: @Hansen, I see you tried to edit Karl Marx's post to add your correction. Please, don't do it; instead, you can add another answer with the correction: "... this answer is a correction for..."

Comment: @IanMateus: I did this because I did not want to claim credit for the solution as the main idea was Karl Marx'. But if writing a new answer is the protocol, I will do so.

Comment: @Hansen It's been a while since you warned him, you surely can do it :-)

Comment: The Hint part is wrong. The minimum of the right hand side is $1$ not $3$.

Comment: Please note the objection from @yegulalp below. It unfortunately invalidates the proof premised on the invariance over variable permutation. Do you have any idea mending the proof or for a new one?

Answer (score 6):

This is to prove $a^{b-1}b^{1-a}\ge 1$ as needed in Ron Ford's answer above. Let $f(b)=(1-b)(-\log a)-(1-a)(-\log b)$, $b\in [a,1]$. $f(a)=f(1)=0$. $f$ is concave, as $f''(b)=-\frac{1-a}{b^2}<0$. So $f(b)>0,\,\forall b\in(a,1)$ and the result follows.

Comment: No problem. I like your solution.

Answer (score 2):

The inequality as posed in the OP appears to be correct.  The accepted proof (Ford/Hansen) is not.

Note that the proof doesn't require the assumption that $x+y+z=1$.  Take $x=6$, $y=2$, and $z=1$.  Then the left side is ${36\over 64} + 2 + {1\over 6} =  2 + {35\over 48} < 3$, violating the inequality.  Clearly the proof cannot be correct as stated.

The error in the Ford/Hansen proof is the assumption we can take $x \leq y \leq z$.  This is not generally possible because the LHS of the inequality is not invariant to permuting any pair of the variables.  Note that if we swap $x$ with $y$, the first term becomes its own reciprocal and the second and third terms become each other's reciprocals:

Define 
$$A = x^{y}/y^{x}, B = y^{z}/z^{y}, C = z^{x}/x^{z}.$$
Exchanging $x$ with $y$ makes $A \rightarrow 1/A$, $B \rightarrow 1/C$, and $C \rightarrow 1/B$.

Furthermore, no proof using the AM-GM inequality can work.  Applying AM-GM we get:
$$ A + B + C \geq 3(ABC)^{1/3}.$$
If $ABC < 1$, we can't finish the proof.  If $ABC > 1$, then consider the case where we swap $x$ and $y$:
$$ A^{-1} + B^{-1} + C^{-1} \geq 3(ABC)^{-1/3}$$
Unless $ABC=1$, the bound is insufficient in one of the two cases above to prove the desired result. If the bound works for a given $x$, $y$, and $z$ then it won't suffice for the case where we swap $x$ and $y$.

Comment: I've removed the erroneous statements and numerical example to which Daniel responded.

Comment: Your objection is correct. Any ideas for a proof or counterexample? Is the reason you say this inequality "appears to be correct" some numerical verification?